# How to do an XPath query on a DOMNode and covert to txt?

Tags: html, file, xpath

i need to extract the `<h2 style="text-align: justify;">` and `<p style="text-align: justify;">` element content using an xpath query and also clean the html inside, to convert it into a txt file.

Here is the source:

```
<div class="blog-content">
<div id="div-gpt-ad-1460730703306-0">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js">googletag.defineSlot('/134284252/corsoitalia-728x90', [[728, 90], [300, 250]], 'div-gpt-ad-1460730703306-0').addService(googletag.pubads()).setTargeting(); googletag.pubads().enableSyncRendering();googletag.enableServices();googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1460730703306-0');</script>
</div>
<p class="no-break">
<span st_url='http://www.corsoitalianews.it/70211-2-mauro-marsu-150317/' st_title='Mauro Marsu presenta Prima dell&#8217;alba al Marianiello il 24 marzo' class='st_facebook_hcount'></span>
<span st_url='http://www.corsoitalianews.it/70211-2-mauro-marsu-150317/' st_title='Mauro Marsu presenta Prima dell&#8217;alba al Marianiello il 24 marzo' class='st_fblike_hcount'></span>
<span st_username='corsoitalianews' st_url='http://www.corsoitalianews.it/70211-2-mauro-marsu-150317/' st_title='Mauro Marsu presenta Prima dell&#8217;alba al Marianiello il 24 marzo' class='st_twitter_hcount'></span>
<span st_url='http://www.corsoitalianews.it/70211-2-mauro-marsu-150317/' st_title='Mauro Marsu presenta Prima dell&#8217;alba al Marianiello il 24 marzo' class='st_googleplus_hcount'></span>
<span st_url='http://www.corsoitalianews.it/70211-2-mauro-marsu-150317/' st_title='Mauro Marsu presenta Prima dell&#8217;alba al Marianiello il 24 marzo' class='st_pinterest_hcount'></span>
<span st_url='http://www.corsoitalianews.it/70211-2-mauro-marsu-150317/' st_title='Mauro Marsu presenta Prima dell&#8217;alba al Marianiello il 24 marzo' class='st_linkedin_hcount'></span></p>
<h2 style="text-align: justify;">Venerdì 24 marzo dalle ore <span title="9:30 nel tuo fuso orario">22:30 presso il Gran Caffè Marianiello di Piano di Sorrento Mauro Marsu presenterà il suo ultimo disco: Prima dell&#8217;alba</span></h2>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><img class="alignleft wp-image-70212" src="http://corsoitalia.pierodecindioweb.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/17155296_1845309335727349_720535044501942857_n-213x300.jpg" width="400" height="563" srcset="http://corsoitalia.pierodecindioweb.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/17155296_1845309335727349_720535044501942857_n-213x300.jpg 213w, http://corsoitalia.pierodecindioweb.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/17155296_1845309335727349_720535044501942857_n.jpg 682w" sizes="(max-width: 400px) 100vw, 400px" />Il prossimo venerdì 24 marzo, presso il Gran Caffè Marianiello di Piano di Sorrento (piazza Cota), si terrà il concerto di presentazione del nuovo disco di <strong>Mauro Marsu</strong>, Prima dell&#8217;alba, disponibile su tutti gli stores digitali e in copia fisica:<br />
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/marsumc" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=1592735873&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22directed_target_id%22%3A1218425214941997%7D" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1">Mauro Marsu</a> &#8211; voce/voce narrante<br />
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/djspidermusic" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=1541390147&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22directed_target_id%22%3A1218425214941997%7D" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1">Roberto DjSpider Ciuoffo</a> &#8211; giradischi</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><strong>Special guests:</strong><br />
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/KatiaDeMartino" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=687303064&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22directed_target_id%22%3A1218425214941997%7D" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1">Katia De Martino</a><br />
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/djneno81" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=585460485&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22directed_target_id%22%3A1218425214941997%7D" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1">Tonino Aprea</a> a.k.a. DJ Neno<br />
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/antonino.staiano.92" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=1108264920&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22directed_target_id%22%3A1218425214941997%7D" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1">Antonino Staiano</a><br />
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/luigi.apredamollo" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=1654098883&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22directed_target_id%22%3A1218425214941997%7D" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1">Luigi Apreda Mollo</a> a.k.a. <a href="https://www.facebook.com/DiamondLouisElite/" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/page.php?id=1259307280770798&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22directed_target_id%22%3A1218425214941997%7D" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1">Diamond Louis</a><br />
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/cristian.izzo.3" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=1648668678&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22directed_target_id%22%3A1218425214941997%7D" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1">Cristian Izzo</a><span class="text_exposed_show"><br />
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/zorama.official/" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/page.php?id=185577451465151&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22directed_target_id%22%3A1218425214941997%7D" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1">Zorama</a></span></p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">Il disco ha un concept particolare e racconta la storia di una notte e dei suoi abitanti, dei suoi attori più o meno protagonisti. È la storia di chi lavora di notte o di chi la vive per divertimento. È un’umana commedia che terminerà al forno di Aniello. Un barbone e una prostituta a far da Angelo e Dea, una casellante, Ada, a far da apripista per l’”ade notturno. Una coppia di innamorati in cerca di amore, un bambino in cerca della tranquillità per riposare, rassicurato dal lampeggiante di un vigilante. Un barista amico di tutti, uno spacciatore, dei ragazzi impegnati in una campagna elettorale che si confronteranno con un’aspirante giornalista, che di fatto, i giornali li consegna. Una tassista che scarrozza persone e ne immagina a sua volta le storie. Un portiere d’albergo che ama i cruciverba, uno spazzino amante del jazz a cui toccherà “ripulire il palco in cui questa notte è andata in scena con i suoi protagonisti e le sue comparse.</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><span class="text_exposed_show"><strong>Un viaggio lungo una notte, tra fantasia e realtà, che vanno ad intrecciarsi&#8230; prima dell’alba. </strong></span></p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><strong>Tante le collaborazioni:</strong><br />
</div>
```

Code sample:

```
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    foreach ($x_path->query('h2|p', $node) as $child) {
        echo $child->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you want just a text content from `h2` and `p` tags or `outerHTML` of those elements without attributes or child nodes? What does `and also clean the html inside` mean?

Comment: Dear @Andersson I need to extract only the text inside the div.
h2 tag is the title, each p tag is the content message. The p tag inside have a lot of html. I need to clear all for insert into a text file

Ex:
Title (from h2 tag)
Text (from the contet o each p tags)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have little experience with `PHP`, so I'm not sure that syntax is 100% correct... Try below code and let me know if this is not exactly what you want:

```
$divs = $x_path->query( '//div[@class="blog-content"]' );
foreach( $divs as $div ){
    $headers=$x_path->query( './h2', $div );
    echo $headers->item(0)->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
    $paragraphs=$x_path->query( './p', $div );
    foreach( $paragraphs as $p ){
        echo $p->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```